# Materialized Path Algorithm

Tags: 1с

Как написать алгоритм создание материализованного пути для дерева значений? Чтобы нумерация была вот такой:

1

1.1    1.2

1.2.1   1.2.2

Написал вот так:

Нумератор = 0;

ОсновнойНумератор = 1;

Функция ПронумероватьДерево(СтрокиДерева,Нумератор)

```
Для каждого СтрокаДерева из СтрокиДерева Цикл       
    
    ТекущийРодитель = СтрокаДерева.Родитель;
    Если ЗначениеЗаполнено(СтрокаДерева.Родитель) Тогда
        СтрокаДерева.НомерСтроки = Строка(Нумератор+".1");
        Нумератор = Нумератор+0.1;
        ПронумероватьДерево(СтрокаДерева.Строки,Нумератор);
    Иначе 
    СтрокаДерева.НомерСтроки = Строка(ОсновнойНумератор);
    НумераторДляСтрок = ОсновнойНумератор;
    ОсновнойНумератор = ОсновнойНумератор+1;
    ПронумероватьДерево(СтрокаДерева.Строки,НумераторДляСтрок);
    КонецЕсли;
    
    
КонецЦикла;
```

КонецФункции

Но вместо 1.2.1 создается 1.3. Подскажите в чем ошибка и как ее исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Для любого уровня вложенности.
Просто передай на вход начальный уровень дерева.

```
Процедура ПронумероватьДерево(СтрокиДерева, КрайнийНомер = 0)
    
    ОсновнойНумератор = 1;
    СчетчикВложеногоУровня = 1;
    
    Для каждого СтрокаДерева Из СтрокиДерева Цикл
        
        ТекущийРодитель = СтрокаДерева.Родитель;
        
        Если ЗначениеЗаполнено(СтрокаДерева.Родитель) Тогда
            СтрокаДерева.НомерСтроки = КрайнийНомер + "." + СчетчикВложеногоУровня;
            ПронумероватьДерево(СтрокаДерева.Строки, СтрокаДерева.НомерСтроки);
            СчетчикВложеногоУровня = СчетчикВложеногоУровня + 1;
        Иначе
            СтрокаДерева.НомерСтроки = Строка(ОсновнойНумератор);
            ОсновнойНумератор = ОсновнойНумератор + 1;
            ПронумероватьДерево(СтрокаДерева.Строки, СтрокаДерева.НомерСтроки);
        КонецЕсли;
        
        
    КонецЦикла;
    
КонецПроцедуры
```